# Capslock/control switching for Raspberry Pi 5 Ubuntu

Tags: capslock

I'd like any way to swap capslock and control or map capslock to control on the Raspberry Pi 5 ubuntu port.  The old xmodmap does not work anymore. I think this is because of the usage of Wayland.

dconf-editor looks promising, as caps:swapescape works for escape.  What is the equivelent for control?

Answer (score 0):

The way to get around this is to opt out of Wayland:

Run raspi-config

Then
Select  6 (Advanced Options) -> A6 (Wayland) ->W1 (X11)
Select X11 and reboot.